# Manage Timer for each List item in the background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a feature in an flutter application. The feature is that when some entry in server (DB) occurs, I get notification through socket connection and add that item in `List`. There is a button on the screen which shows a dialog box on clicking and shows that list of items. We can close the box also and again open when required.

Now I want to attach `Timer` to each item in the `List`. The purpose of that timer is to delete the item from the list after 1 minute. All that functionality of removing items must keep going in the background when dialog box doesn't appear. On opening the dialog box it must shows updated List each time.

Right now I am able to add items to the list and showing them in dialog box and it is working.

I just want to find out the solution of that background running task in which items automatically remove from list after the time for that item is up.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to perform an action after one minute might be to just await a future like this:

```dart
Future<void> deleteAfter1Minute() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes: 1));
  // delete item from list
  // ... your code
  print('item deleted');
}
```

You can also initiate a timer which fires the callback after the given duration:

```dart
final timer = Timer(const Duration(minutes: 1), () {
  // delete item from list
  // ... your code
  print('item deleted');
  timer.cancel();
});
```

It might also help if you attached some code to better understand where you're coming from.

Best

Answer (score 0):

**you can use the background service packages for that**

[flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service)

that is very good package for background service

Comment: I need a plugin for desktop flutter application.

Comment: It only supports iOS and Android

Comment: did you want your app to update list when app is closed or only to update list when app working on other functionlity

Comment: if you want to change the list you can also use the dart  isolates for that